# User Permissions Problem

Tags: permissions

user xyz is member in group A and group B. In group A user xyz have visitor permissions. In group B user xyz have Full access. Group A and B are given access to a site. Then which  permission for user xyz will get for that site???. visitor or full access ???

Answer (score 3):

Full access, the highest granted permission on a particular level will win